# PowerShell regular expression to get all the HTML tags

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string with HTML tags. I have to write PowerShell script to split this string using regular expression for HTML tags both opening and closing. I have tried many times but with no luck.
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)[^>]*>
I have tried this for opening tags. But it only removes the '<' and '>' from string not the whole tag.
My string is something like this:

```
    <Div id="div1">
<Div>
some text inside.
</Div>
<font>this is text inside font.
</font>
<h1>this is h1 text.
</h1>
<p>
This is a new paragraph.
</p>
</Div>
```

My desired output is: some text inside. This is text inside font. this is h1 text. This is a new paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you're doing your split, but it shouldn't be that difficult:

```
$Text = 
@'
   <Div id="div1">
<Div>
some text inside.
</Div>
<font>this is text inside font.
</font>
<h1>this is h1 text.
</h1>
<p>
This is a new paragraph.
</p>
</Div>
'@

$text -split '<.+?>' -match '\S'

some text inside.

this is text inside font.

this is h1 text.    

This is a new paragraph.
```

Comment: @Matt Thanks for reply. Its not working. First '@' is giving error as recognized token. Second is '<.+?>' is not working. Please suggest something.

Comment: I had tried '<.*>' but its only removing '<' and '>'.

Comment: The here-string (the @'- '@) is just creating test data.  You need to substitute your actual data for $text. The '<.+?>' regex seemed to work fine in testing.  I can't "suggest something" without knowing what "not working" means.

Comment: @Asu What do you mean it is not working? This tested for me just fine as well

Comment: I just updated the answer to include the result of running that regex against your posted test data.  If that's not what you want, then I've misunderstood the question.  If you are getting different results, then your data is not the same as what you've posted.

Comment: $string = "<Div><font>this is text inside font.</font><h1>this is h1 text.</h1></Div>"
write-host $string
$array = $text -split "<.+?>"
write-host $array

<Div><font>this is text inside font.</font><h1>this is h1 text.</h1></Div>

Comment: above is my ouput...nothing is shown..no error also

Comment: Why are you splitting $text, when your data is in $string?  $text is the variable name I used for the example. You need to replace that with the variable ($string) that actually has your data in it.

Comment: sorry it gave me the ouput I wanted..I was doing something wrong..Thanks a lot